# How to populate dropdown based on another dropdown for specific row in react-table v.6

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-table

I have two columns with dropdowns. When I choose option from any dropdown of first column, list of options should changes in second column's dropdown in the same row. In reality, it impacts for whole column and makes changes in all dropdowns.
[image]

How to make that the changes in left dropdown will impact to next right dropdown only?
This is my code:

```
const contact = {
"Phone #": [
    { val: 0, text: 'Cell Phone' },
    { val: 1, text: 'Home Phone' },
    { val: 2, text: 'Office Phone 1' },
    { val: 3, text: 'Office Phone 2' },
    { val: 4, text: 'Phone 10' },
    { val: 5, text: 'Phone 2' },
    { val: 6, text: 'Phone 4' },
    { val: 7, text: 'Phone 5' },
    { val: 8, text: 'Phone 6' },
    { val: 9, text: 'Phone 7' },
    { val: 10, text: 'Phone 8' },
    { val: 11, text: 'Phone 9' },
    { val: 12, text: 'Primary Contact Type' }
],
"E-mail": [
    { val: 0, text: 'Credit Card Notices only email' },
    { val: 1, text: 'Email 1' },
    { val: 2, text: 'Email 2' },
    { val: 3, text: 'Email 3' },
    { val: 4, text: 'Email 4' },
    { val: 5, text: 'ePrice Quote only email' },
    { val: 6, text: 'pegasus Tablet Email' },
    { val: 7, text: 'Statement only email Address' }
],
"DTN": [
    { val: 0, text: 'DTN #1' },
    { val: 1, text: 'DTN #2' },
    { val: 2, text: 'DTN #3' }
]
 }
```

And

```
class ContactDocMaintenance extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: { data },
        defValue: false,
        contactValue: 'Phone #'
    }
}
onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ contactValue: value });
}
render() {
    const { contactValue } = this.state;
    const options = contact[contactValue];
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-8">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 mt-2">
                        <ContentCard name="Contact Information" >
                            <ReactTable
                                data={data}
                                keyField="id"
                                pageSizeOptions={[20, 30, 50, 100, 200, 500]}
                                columns={[
                                    {
                                        Header: "Status",
                                        accessor: "status",
                                        width: 100,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        Header: "Contact Type",
                                        id: "contactType",
                                        accessor: "contactType",
                                        width: 100,
                                        Cell: row => (<select onChange={this.onChange} margins="m-0" >
                                            < option value="Phone #" > Phone #</option>
                                            <option value="E-mail">E-mails</option>
                                            <option value="DTN">DTN</option>
                                        </select>)
                                    },
                                    {
                                        Header: "Contact Type Description",
                                        accessor: "contactTypeDescription",
                                        width: 200,
                                        Cell: row => (<select margins="m-0" >{options.map((opt) => <option key={opt.val} value={opt.val}>{opt.text}</option>)}</select>)
                                    },
                                    {
                                        Header: "Contact value",
                                        accessor: "contactValue",
                                        width: 100
                                    },
                                    {
                                        Header: "Notification",
                                        accessor: "notification",
                                        width: 100
                                    }
                                ]}
                                defaultPageSize={10}
                                className="-highlight"
                                showPagination={false}
                            />
                        </ContentCard>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default ContactDocMaintenance;
```

Data:

```
const data = [    {
"status": "",
"contactType": "",
"contactTypeDescription": "",
"contactValue": "(235)253-4524",
"notification": "",
},
{
"status": "",
"contactType": "",
 "contactTypeDescription": "",
"contactValue": "(450)454-7878",
"notification": "",
},
 {
  "status": "",
 "contactType": "",
 "contactTypeDescription": "",
 "contactValue": "(514)777-7777",
 "notification": "",
 },
{
"status": "",
"contactType": "",
"contactTypeDescription": "",
"contactValue": "(235)253-4524",
 "notification": "",
},
 {
  "status": "",
   "contactType": "",
  "contactTypeDescription": "",
 "contactValue": "(450)454-7878",
  "notification": "",
  },
 {
    "status": "",
   "contactType": "",
   "contactTypeDescription": "",
    "contactValue": "(514)777-7777",
   "notification": "",
   },
 {
    "status": "",
  "contactType": "",
  "contactTypeDescription": "",
  "contactValue": "(514)777-7777",
  "notification": "",
  }, 
  {
  "status": "",
  "contactType": "",
  "contactTypeDescription": "",
 "contactValue": "(450)454-7878",
  "notification": "",
  },
  {
  "status": "",
  "contactType": "",
  "contactTypeDescription": "",
 "contactValue": "(450)454-7878",
 "notification": "",
   },
{
  "status": "",
  "contactType": "",
  "contactTypeDescription": "",
  "contactValue": "(450)454-7878",
  "notification": "",
   }

 ]
```

Comment: In the constructor what is `data: { data }`?

Comment: Data is variable with array of objects.

Comment: Can you include an example of Data?

Comment: Added  an example